# Modern tools for JSON serialization in an ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm currently learning how to program in ASP.net. I'm interested in taking records from a database and simply serializing the results into JSON to deliver to the client. Are there any modern tools to assist in the JSON serialization? Ideally something like the following in in Ruby on Rails would be fantasy:

`foo = Foo.find(1)`
`foo.to_json` # deliver the results here to the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newtonsoft's [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is among the most popular these days. You can install it via NuGet.

Keep in mind that if you are using Web APIs, the returned object is automatically serialized for you based on formatters installed in your project. By default, XML and JSON are used, so you can just return your model type and the client will receive it in Json format.